# Why does PostgreSQL perform sequential scan on indexed column?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sequence, database-scan

Very simple example - one table, one index, one query:

```
CREATE TABLE book
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  "year" integer,
  -- other columns...
);

CREATE INDEX book_year_idx ON book (year)

EXPLAIN
 SELECT *
   FROM book b
  WHERE b.year > 2009
```

gives me:

```
Seq Scan on book b  (cost=0.00..25663.80 rows=105425 width=622)
  Filter: (year > 2009)
```

Why it does NOT perform index scan instead?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 387, accepted):

If the SELECT returns more than approximately 5-10% of all rows in the table, a sequential scan is much faster than an index scan.

This is because an index scan requires *several* IO operations for each row (look up the row in the index, then retrieve the row from the heap). Whereas a sequential scan only requires a single IO  for each row - or even less because a block (page) on the disk contains more than one row, so more than one row can be fetched with a single IO operation.

Btw: this is true for other DBMS as well - some optimizations as "index only scans" taken aside (but for a SELECT * it's highly unlikely such a DBMS would go for an "index only scan")

Comment: Interesting, that explains many things for me :)
Indeed, when I select by year > 2010 it does index scan.
Thank you!

Comment: Also, a sequential scan can request several pages from the heap at a time, and ask the kernel to be fetching the next chunk while it works on the current one- an index scan fetches one page at once. (A bitmap scan does a compromise between the two, you usually see that appearing in a plan for queries that aren't selective enough for an index scan, but still not so unselective as to merit a full table scan)

Comment: The interesting question is how the database knows how many rows the query will return without doing it first? Does it store stats such as the number of different values vs table size somewhere?

Comment: @LaurentGrégoire: yes, the database stores statistics about the number of rows and the distribution of values. See the manual for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/planner-stats.html

Comment: and what about the case where you are sure that the index scan is better? in local db it uses the index and is much faster, on production it prefers seq. scan

Comment: @brauliobo: without more information that is impossible to answer. The usual suspects are wrong (outdated) statistics on the table or different configurations (of the optimizer) in the two servers.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in this case it depend on a where condition of a joined table: if I used the where specifically on the table I want the index to be used, then it used the index and it was much faster. If otherwise I use the column on the original table, not the joined colum/table, which btw have much more rows, then it wouldn't use index and be much slower. It seems a bug on the planner to me...

Comment: @brauliobo: please post a new question for this. Comments are not the right place to discuss a completely new question

Comment: I would imagine a star select also makes the index less "useable".

Answer (score 21):

Did you [ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-analyze.html) the table/database? And what about the [statistics](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-statistic.html)? When there are many records where year > 2009, a sequential scan might be faster than an index scan.

Answer (score 7):

@a_horse_with_no_name explained it quite well. Also if you really want to use an index scan, you should generally use bounded ranges in where clause. eg - 
year > 2019 and year < 2020.

A lot of the times statistics are not updated on a table and it may not be possible to do so due to constraints. In this case, the optimizer will not know how many rows it should take in year > 2019. Thus it selects a sequential scan in lieu of full knowledge. Bounded partitions will solve the problem most of the time.

Answer (score 6):

In index scan, read head jumps from one row to another which is 1000 times slower than reading the next physical block (in the sequential scan).

So, if the (number of records to be retrieved * 1000) is less than the total number of records, the index scan will perform better.