# Efficient way to check if row exists for multiple records in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, query-optimization, postgresql-9.3

I saw answers to a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471625/fastest-check-if-row-exists-in-postgresql), but couldn't really apply what they are doing to my specific case.

I have a large table (300k rows) that I need to join with another even larger (1-2M rows) table efficiently. For my purposes, I only need to know whether a matching row exists in the second table. I came up with a nested query like so:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  CASE cnt WHEN 0 then 'NO_MATCH' else 'YES_MATCH' end as match_exists
FROM 
  (
   SELECT 
     A.id as id, count(*) as cnt
   FROM
     A, B
   WHERE 
     A.id = B.foreing_id
   GROUP BY A.id
  ) AS id_and_matches_count
```

Is there a better and/or more efficient way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want a left outer join:

```
SELECT 
   A.id as id, count(B.foreing_id) as cnt
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON
    A.id = B.foreing_id
GROUP BY A.id
```

Comment: actually, my attempt was incorrect. thanks for providing proper query, but is there more efficient way to do it considering the fact that I only need to know whether count(B.foreign_id) is = 0 or > 0?

Comment: @Tomato, if there were a way to select only one row from B for each A, you could avoid the `GROUP BY`.  Like, if the first row for B that exists were always labeled 1 in another column, you could add a condition for that and avoid grouping.   Otherwise, this is pretty much it.

Comment: thanks a lot for pointers! There is no additional column in our current schema, thus I will stick with current approach for now.