# Case-statment in postgresql for doing different things depending on if a column exist or not

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to do a Case-statment in postgres to do different things depending on if a column exist or not,

```
CASE 
WHEN select exists (select * from information_schema.columns where 
table_name = 'mytable' and column_name = 'mycolumnt')
THEN select mycolumn from mytable where mycolumnt = true
ELSE select mycolumn from mytable
END
```

After executing the case statement I got below error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "case"

Any tips what I'm doing wrong? My postgres-knowledge is pretty basic.

Comment: Its CASE WHEN [evaluation] THEN [statement] END https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471625/fastest-check-if-row-exists-in-postgresql

Comment: @Doomenik checked that question before but can't figure out how to apply it on my problem.

Comment: Max Answer should work for you

Comment: Should maybe but that doesn't mean it does.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should start with `SELECT`. Like:

```
SELECT mycolumn
FROM mytable
WHERE CASE WHEN exists (
     select * 
     from information_schema.columns 
     where table_name = 'mytable' and column_name = 'mycolumnt')
   THEN mycolumnt = true
   ELSE true
   END
```

Also, I would recommend you to always have **mycolumnt**, just set it to **false** when there is no translation. This would simplify your query to this:

```
SELECT mycolumn
FROM mytable
WHERE mycolumnt = true
```

Comment: That sound right, but when I wright it like that I get ERROR:  column "mycolumnt" does not exist when the column is'nt.

Comment: So mytable may not have mycolumn in some cases?

Comment: no exactly my bad, mycolumn always exist but not mycolumnt, mycolumnt is a translate-column for a boolean-value if a value in mycolumn should be translated or not, but if all the values should be translated there isn't a mycolumnt.

Comment: Yes it had absolute been easier to always have mycolumnt, but the code is meant to be for many tables and columns and if every column has a translate-column it would be a lot of columns.