# Connection leak in lib/pq postgres driver

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

Given that `db` is of type `*sql.DB` (uging `lib/pq` driver), the following code causes connection leak:

```golang
    rows, err := db.Query(
        "select 1 from things where id = $1",
        thing,
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("can't select thing (%d): %w", thing, err)
    }

    found := false

    for rows.Next() {
        found = true
        break
    }
```

Calling this code repeatedly increases the number of open connections, until exhausted:

```sql
select sum(numbackends) from pg_stat_database;
// 5
// 6
// 7
// ...
// 80
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple problems with your code as written. The direct answer to your question of avoiding connection leaks is to close the `rows` iterator [as mentioned in the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Close). The normal way to call it is in a `defer` statement:

```golang
    rows, err := db.Query(
        "select 1 from things where id = $1",
        thing,
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("can't select thing (%d): %w", thing, err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    found := false

    for rows.Next() {
        found = true
        break
    }
```

Second, since all you ever care about is a single result, there's no reason to fetch a multi-row result set at all, which will implicitly solve the connection leak issue, as well. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16467634/13860) for a discussion on the quickest way to check for existence in Postgres. If we adapt that here:

```golang
    row, err := db.QueryRow(
        "select EXISTS(SELECT 1 from things where id = $1)",
        thing,
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("can't select thing (%d): %w", thing, err)
    }
    var found bool
    if err := row.Scan(&found); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Failed to scan result: %w", err)
    }
```