# Query for retrieve matching json Objects as a list

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Assume i have a table called **MyTable** and this table have a JSON type column called **myjson** and this column have next value as a json array hold multiple objects, for example like next:

```
[
  {
    "budgetType": "CF",
    "financeNumber": 1236547,
    "budget": 1000000
  },
  {
    "budgetType": "ENVELOPE",
    "financeNumber": 1236888,
    "budget": 2000000
  }
]
```

So how i can **search** if the record has any JSON objects inside its JSON array with **financeNumber=1236547**

Comment: This link provide json operator you can use: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html

Comment: @MeyssamToluie the link you provided is to an EOL version of Postgres. Furthermore there have been a lot of additions to the `JSON` functions and a whole new JSON type `JSONB` added along with functions for the new type. The appropriate link is [JSON(B) Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html).

Comment: Are you using the `json` or `jsonb` type?

Comment: i am using JSON type, but i can't find the function which i can use to filter out the property inside the objects of the array, that's why i wrote the question here. i hope any one can suggest any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    "MyTable",
    LATERAL json_to_recordset(myjson) AS t ("budgetType" varchar,
        "financeNumber" int,
        budget varchar)
WHERE
    "financeNumber" = 1236547;
```

Obviously not tested on your data, but it should provide a starting point.

Comment: Just tested, works fine, thank you.

Comment: FYI, if you use the `jsonb` type you get to use the [SQL/JSON Path Language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH).

Answer (score 0):

```
with a as(
 SELECT  json_array_elements(myjson)->'financeNumber'  as col   FROM mytable)
select exists(select from a where col::text = '1236547'::text );
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html
`json_array_elements` return setof json, so you need cast.
Check if a row exists: [Fastest check if row exists in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471625/fastest-check-if-row-exists-in-postgresql)